# Analyzing a Gambling Race Paradox

Tags: expected-value, simulation, paradoxes, gambling, risk-assessment

Suppose a number of players are given $100$ points each, and repeatedly engage in a gamble having positive expected value, with the goals of being the first player to reach $100000$ points.  Solving for the optimal bet size per round to balance risk of ruin and speed of point accrual is a very difficult game theory problem, so the reasonable approach seems to be to impose a heuristic constraint on the risk of ruin, and optimize speed relative to that constraint.  Let's say I decide I want no more than a $2$% probability of going bankrupt before reaching the $100000$ point goal.  Now I can simulate the game a large number of times to find the bet size which reaches the goal in as few rounds as possible (probably the largest bet size) without exceeding the target risk of ruin.

However, suppose I am playing the game in practice, and have accrued a point total of $1000$.  The remainder of the game is functionally equivalent to a new, identical game, except that in the new game, I start with $1000$ points instead of $100$ points.  In other words, the game I've been describing has an optimal substructure.  It seems to me that in the new game, my desired risk of ruin constraint should still be about the same, $2$% in the example; there seems to be no fundamental reason (apart from assessing my position relative to other players, which is beyond the scope of this question) to suppose I would have a different risk tolerance in the race from $1000$ to $100000$ than in the race from $100$ to $100000$.  Allowing the risk of ruin to decline too much as the game progresses is an unnecessary speed concession.

The problem is that changing my strategy as the game progresses to retarget a $2$% risk of ruin means my original strategy actually had more than a $2$% risk of ruin.  My present, $1000$ point self shouldn't care about this enough to dissuade me from retargeting (the past is in the past), but my past $100$ point self foreseeing this phenomenon cares a lot.  It seems that what's needed is a function which maps every possible point total between $1$ and $99999$ to a bet size, where the risk of ruin at every input is more or less constant (maybe lower at the very end of the game due to the discreteness of the problem), but it is unclear that such a function is possible because attaining points should always reduce risk of ruin no matter what function is selected.  Is is possible to construct such a function?  If not, how can it be rational to select bet sizes with variable risk of ruin when one's underlying preferences don't change much as games progress?

Comment: This problem has been researched extensively.  There's an intro at https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/joma/Volume8/Siegrist/RedBlack.pdf

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks, this was an interesting read, but from what I gathered it does not address the paradox in this question, or even consider the perspective of engineering a favorable-trial strategy around a maximum risk tolerance.

Comment: Unless the optimum strategy give a probability of success of at least $98\%$, there doesn't seem to be any way of limiting the risk of going broke to less than $2\%$, so I would think you'd start by figuring out what the optimum is.  As to the paradox, I don't understand it.

Comment: @saulspatz The optimum strategy for the positive expected value game is very close to $100$%.  As the linked article explains, betting $1$ point every round minimizes the risk to almost $0$%.  But this is takes too many rounds to be viable.

Comment: @saulspatz Stating the paradox another way, it seems that any function mapping my current point total to a bet size will have the property that risk of ruin decreases as point total increases.

Comment: Since my earlier 100 point self cannot force my later 1000 point self (who does not have decreased risk of ruin preferences) to stick to the original function for prescribing bet sizes, it seems my 100 point self is forced to take on more risk than initially desired, regardless of what function is chosen.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it.  I have to think about this more.